# MapsItemControl and ObservableCollection behaviour

Tags: c#, maps, observablecollection, uwp-xaml

I have the next MapsItemControl template to show many pins/items over the map. It is binded to a ObservableCollection because I want them filtered to be shown or hidden by different options. This is the XAML code for the MapsItemControl inside the Map control.

```
<Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapSpotsItems">
    <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="spotPin" Visibility="{Binding isVisible}"
                        Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding geopoint}" Tag="{Binding ID}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Description}" 
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" Tapped="spotPin_Tapped">


                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="{Binding ID}">
                     <Grid>
                         <!-- Karratua -->
                         <Rectangle Width="25" Height="25" Fill="{StaticResource DarkGreyThemeColor}" Opacity="0.5"/>
                         <Rectangle Width="25" Height="25" Fill="{x:Null}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" />
                         <!-- Borobila -->
                         <Image Source="{Binding MainTag}" Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                      </Grid>

                      <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource DarkGrey75ThemeColor}">
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" MaxLines="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="11" Foreground="{StaticResource LightGreyThemeColor}" LineHeight="11"/>
                       </StackPanel>
                   </StackPanel>

                   <Rectangle Width="2" Height="10" Fill="Black" StrokeThickness="0" StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle" />

               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
       </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </Maps:MapItemsControl>
```

And this is the **DataModel**:

```
        private class SpotElement
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Visibility isVisible { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }

        public Visibility score1 { get; set; }
        public Visibility score2 { get; set; }
        public Visibility score3 { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public double Distance { get; set; }

        public Geopoint geopoint { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Altitude { get; set; }

        public DateTime[] Date { get; set; }

        public globalVars.TagImageURL[] Tag { get; set; }
        public string MainTag { get; set; }

        public Point NormalizedAnchorPoint { get; set; }

        public string grouping { get; set; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SpotElement> allSpots;
```

I have some problems related with it.

1. When I change the ObservableCollection, like the isVisible value (to show or to hide by the choices in the filter, the items didn't change at all. 
   This is the code that filters for the visibility of the items:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Filtratu egiten ditu erakutsi beharreko spot-ak
   /// </summary>
   private void FilterSpots()
   {
       foreach (var item in allSpots)
       {
           // TODO: tag-ak falta dira filtratzeko
           bool visibilitySelected = true;
           if (Filter.showOnlySelected)
           {
               visibilitySelected = (item.isSelected == true);
           }
           bool visibilityBool = visibilitySelected && item.Rating >= Filter.minRating;
           Visibility visible = GlobalFunc.BoolToVisibility(visibilityBool);

           if (visible != item.isVisible)
           {
               item.isVisible = visible;
           }

           //Debug.WriteLine(item.Title + ": Rating {0} >= {1}? " + item.isVisible, item.Rating, Filter.minRating);
       }
       //mapSpotsItems.ItemsSource = null;
       //mapSpotsItems.ItemsSource = allSpots;
   }
   ```

   The commented Debug line is the one that I used to check if values on the ObservableCollection (allSpots) are correct. 
   The next 2 lines (mapSpotsItems.ItemsSource = null; and mapSpotsItems.ItemsSource = allSpots;) are the only one mode that I have got items to be filtered. I think that it's the worst way to do that, but while testing it worked despite of the time needed to hide and to show again (sometimes like 20 seconds that the map doesn't work properly).
   Here the way I check if value is true then visibility is visible and if false then collapsed.

   ```
       /// <summary>
   /// Booleanetik Visibility-ra itzultzen du. True bada pasatako booleana, Visible izango da; Collapsed bestela.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="testBool"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public static Visibility BoolToVisibility(bool testBool)
   {
       if (testBool) return Visibility.Visible;
       else return Visibility.Collapsed;
   }
   ```
2. The creation of the items (I have like 2000-3000 item) is very slow and when panning the map the move with a visible lag. Is it any way to make it more pleasant and responsive?
3. And the last question, despite I have set RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" it is as if I had set RenderTransformOrigin="0.0,0.0", rendered from the upper left boundary. [image]. If you look at the image, the item is rendered from the red dot, not from the blue one as it should be rendered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I change the ObservableCollection, like the isVisible value (to show or to hide by the choices in the filter, the items didn't change at all.

[`Visibility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visibility) is `Enum` but not `bool`. You need to make `BoolToVisConverter` for xaml.

```
public class BoolToVisConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible; 
    }
}
```

> The creation of the items (I have like 2000-3000 item) is very slow and when panning the map the move with a visible lag. Is it any way to make it more pleasant and responsive?

`MapItemsControl` is different with `ListView` and `GridView`, it does not support [UI virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.rendertransformorigin). For performance, please avoid render too many items at once

> And the last question, despite I have set RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" it is as if I had set RenderTransformOrigin="0.0,0.0", rendered from the upper left boundary.

[`RenderTransformOrigin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.rendertransformorigin) property is not used to set `AnchorPoint`. For setting right layout you could set [`NormalizedAnchorPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.normalizedanchorpoint).

```
<maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button x:Name="mapItemButton" Click="mapItemButton_Click" Background="Transparent">
            <StackPanel>
                <Border Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </Border>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSourceUri}"
                           maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding NormalizedAnchorPoint}"
                           maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}">
                    <Image.Transitions>
                        <TransitionCollection>
                            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
                        </TransitionCollection>
                    </Image.Transitions>
                </Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

For more detail, please refer official code [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/MapControl/cs/Scenario3.xaml.cs#L56).

Comment: 1- That's not the problem I'm having that when I changed in the data origin the value of Visibility, pin-items are not hidden/shown. They stay the same way as if there were not changes in the ObservableCollection. 
2- Is there any other way to have in the map that many items all around the world but not in the screen all of them at the same time, and be fluid in the execution? This is a must.

Comment: 3- It worked, but still hace some questions why if you use Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5, 1" as I trying before RenderTransformOrigin doesn't work but if you use Binding to the same values it works. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: if the answer  is helpful please consider accept it.

Comment: It solved one part. Still I'm trying to get a solution for hiding and showing the items when I change the filter.

Comment: Yep, could you mind share data model that contain isVisible property and I will test tomorrow.

Comment: I think you need not set `Visibility` property, you just remove the item from collection,  if you want hide that. right?

Comment: I have added more information in the question above.

Answering to your last question, I want to hide but not delete them, because if I want them back I only have to change `isVisible` value to visible and I have them back.